# Как решить эту проблему в видео (overlay)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mejs-overlay-button').click(function() {
        $('.mejs-controls').css("visibility", "visible");
    })
    $(".mejs-controls button").attr("title", "");
});
```

Есть слайдер Bootstrap 4 carousel. В слайдах есть видеоплейер mediaelementjs.
Как сделать, чтобы в слайдере во всех слайдах слассы mejs-overlay-button работали отдельно.

Comment: Подключите необходимую библиотеку в снипет. Чтобы не было ошибок